# how to read text field from bigquery line by line?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in Bigquery which has a text from PDF files.

BIGQUERY: Select text from sample.file1

OUTPUT:

In this article, I’d like to reacquaint you with the humble workhorse of communication that is the paragraph. Paragraphs are everywhere. In fact, at the high risk of stating the obvious, you are reading one now. Despite their ubiquity, we frequently neglect their presentation. This is a mistake.

**August 07,2022**

This is a mistake. Here, we’ll refer to some time-honored typesetting conventions, with an emphasis on readability, and offer guidance on adapting them effectively for devices and screens. We’ll see that the ability to embed fonts with @font-face is not by itself a solution to all of our typographic challenges.

I want to extract the date in a query and the line number will change from doc to doc.
Need help to get this done. tried split , substr, REGEXP_EXTRACT

Comment: are you saying that date that you want to extract resides on its own line and is only what is on that line? and that is why you think you want to read line by line? also, is date format is fixed to what is shown in your question - or it can be in any format?

Comment: yes Mikhail, The format remains same and this is something which is a OCR text extract from a PDF using Doc AI. The whole text of the PDF is captured in a text field in bigquery. substr is useless since each doc has its own lines before the date. this is actually a document received date.